# Given function of a curve, how to solve the best minimum transformation to fit a new set of points?

Tags: math, curve-fitting

Given function of a curve, I want to move it to fit a new set of points and keep the trend of the old curve. Minor curvature adjustments are allowed.

Comment: One possibility is to perform a new regression with all data points, using the previous fitted parameters as the initial parameter estimates for the new regression.